# How to fix JobExecutionException in Java?

Tags: java, listener

I have error in my program:

```
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] INFO org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT_GROUP.HelloJob threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: Testing Exception
    at CronTriggertes.HelloJob.execute(HelloJob.java:15)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:206)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:548)
```

I don't know how to fix it.

```
package CronTriggertes;
package CronTriggertes;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{
        System.out.println("Hello World Quartz Scheduler with CronTrigger: " + new Date());                 throw new JobExecutionException("Testing Exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not enough to clarify the reason. Post code throwing this exception.

Comment: Obviously something in `HelloJob.java:15`. You didn't paste the code so we can't help you.

Comment: Please post code that throws the exception.

Comment: i just add helloJob.java :)

Comment: sorry @user714965 ather erros just shows up :'(

Answer (score 0):

You can find description of this exception here:

http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionException.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove `throw new JobExecutionException("Testing Exception");` from the code... It is directly related to `Job DEFAULT_GROUP.HelloJob threw a JobExecutionException`